# Haproxy + keepalived in google compute engine

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm really new with this technology, and I can't found information regarding this.
I'm trying to migrate a cluster solution to google compute engine, creating 4 webservers with a loadbancer.
I was thinking to use haproxy and keepalived, but is this possible? can I request a VIP? 
I didn't see the option to request a VIP.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reserve an IP address, and then add it to an instance when you launch it.

In GCE, those are called "Reserved IP Addresses", the [documentation shows how you reserve them and assign them](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/instances_and_network#reservedaddress).

Comment: Any idea how to attach it ? I need to create a route rule?

Comment: @FedericoSciarretta It's on the same page, just a bit below

Comment: Yes I saw it, but seems is not possible create a loadbalancing (keepalived + haproxy) in GCE, I'm really confuse about how to create a high availability and loadbalancer webserver environment with this google solution.